# On the LSA Summer Linguistic Institute

Tags: soft-question

I'm terribly sorry if this is considered off-topic, but I couldn't find a more appropriate community to ask.

The question is about Summer Linguistic Institutes, in particular, the one held in 2019 in UC Davis. I'm new to linguistics, and I couldn't find any information on the [official website](http://lsa2019.ucdavis.edu/) regarding the two things. First of all, is it suitable for a linguistics newbie? According to the list of courses, they are introductory, but does it mean that one can feel comfortable with having no background in linguistics? Second of all, regarding the financial aspect. In some non-linguistic areas, most workshops are free and provide financial support for participants. What about this Institute? Is the admission free? Is there any financial support available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to 5 or so of these institutes as a student; was an administrator at one in 1969; taught phonology at one.  Should be fun.  I wouldn't worry about being unprepared, since there is such a variety of students there, instructors (who are from all over) know they can't count on any particular shared background in their classes.  If you don't know anything, be prepared to do some extra reading.

I glanced over your web reference.  It looks like they are just getting organized, so exactly who will teach what is probably still up in the air.  I didn't recognized any linguists' names.

I suppose there will be some opportunities for financial aid.  You should check that with your home institution, as well. You might think about not actually being admitted formally as a student, but just going to classes and hanging out (as I did).

Personally, I would not be interested in attending an Institute with a methodological slant, as this one promises to be.